# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Go to XY" tool

Tags: qgis, coordinates, xy, callout

I am wondering if there is a way to quickly add coordinates on the map as a callout (without the need of creating a shapefile).

For example, ArcMap has a nice feature (Go to XY) where you can simple insert a coordinate and it places a callout or label in your workspace.

Does anyone knows if QGIS has something similar?

[image]

Comment: The [lat lon tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/) plugins lets you zoom and add a marker... but no callout.  (Make sure you are comfortable with the developer's organization before installing this handy plugin)

Comment: Just to show where a coordinate is, put de coordinates separated by coma (,) in the lower left corner search box.

Comment: Is your need the callout, or to bookmark some places to easily go-to/zoom-to ? If the latter, then you have Bookmark editor

Comment: @JGH  lat_lon_tools is the best solution for now, but it can only place one marker at the time unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the locator bar for that - the small search bar in the lower left corner from QGIS, just put your coordinates in there, no plugin needed:

[image]

Comment: Handy indeed, but it does not place a quick label on the map for quick viewing and comparisons, especially when you quickly want to measure distance to hasty given coords.